# how to validate Date range search in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Wanted to validate the json data on date range search in Jmeter.

Scenario as follows .

1. Search for a data on specific date range (Ex: Studies from 25/05/2020 to 30/05/2020)
2. Validate the JSon response data.

Example Json response data:

"showAdditionAccNo":false,
"diagnosisNumber":null,
"secondOpinionReqTo":"",
"patientdbid":,
"streamingServerIp":"",
**"lastUpdateTime":"19-12-2019 15:38:34",**
"caseLockInfo":"",

I need to validate this lastupdatetime value for date range search.So need to know how and what is the feasible way to achive.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what do you mean by "validate", if your JSON response looks like:

```
{
  "showAdditionAccNo": false,
  "diagnosisNumber": null,
  "secondOpinionReqTo": "",
  "patientdbid": "",
  "streamingServerIp": "",
  "lastUpdateTime": "19-12-2019 15:38:34",
  "caseLockInfo": ""
}
```

you can extract the `lastUpdateTime` value using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) and the next [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query:

```
$.lastUpdateTime
```

[image]

Once done you can compare the variable value with the reference value using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) or other appropriate Assertion type (depending on what does your "validate" statement stands for)